# Build on build server fails on Any CPU, but works fine on x86 or x64

Tags: c#

I've got a project that builds on a build server (TFS), and works fine if the build configuration is x86 or x64. Take that same project, set it to Any CPU, and I get this error:

> SGEN: An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: `...\....dll`.

It is also worth mentioning that all 3 build configurations work fine on my local development machine.

Any thoughts on what I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message occurs when you try to load an assembly built for x64 in an x86 process or vice versa.

An assembly that is built for AnyCPU can be loaded in an x64 or x86 assembly because it will JIT to x64 or x86 depending on the bitness of the process loading it.

There are a LOT of possible causes for this error related to TFS builds.  My recommendation is to search SO for "SGEN: An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format" and start stepping through the solutions already posted.  Seriously this is a very common problem with different solutions based on your post-build events, setting your build workflow toolplatform, etc.